# how to sand-plaster a plaster wall without spreading plaster dust everywhere?

Tags: drywall, plaster, sanding

I have the following wall I need to sand

[image].

Issue is the wall is made of plaster.

- Is there a way to sand it without spreading plaster dust all over my kitchen, please?

Thanks.

Comment: Is that loose paint, in the picture?

Comment: hi @tahwos what do you mean by loose paint, please?

Comment: It looks like flakes of paint, on the surface.

Comment: @tahwos it is flake of paints

Comment: Then your first course of action, would be to remove all of the loose paint, with scrapers and a stiff brush.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [Drywall Vacuum sander http://amzn.to/2uWPcdB](http://amzn.to/2uWPcdB) that connects to a vacuum. The vacuum will pick up the vast majority of dust that gets created.

These things use a special abrasive screen/sandpaper that allows the dust being created to pass through the screen/sandpaper and into your vacuum cleaner. This also helps prevent the abrasives from clogging due to dust.